# C# unable to enroll a device in Autopilot using graph ImportedWindowsAutopilotDeviceIdentities

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I have a powershell function that calls a C# function app to enroll a device in Autopilot. I can't get it to work. I'm quite sure the problem lies with the hardware identifier binary blob. I tried every string format but I always get the same error

Here's how the hardware identifier is retreived in powershell

```
 $devDetail = (Get-CimInstance -CimSession $session -Namespace root/cimv2/mdm/dmmap -Class MDM_DevDetail_Ext01 -Filter "InstanceID='Ext' AND ParentID='./DevDetail'")

        if ($devDetail -and (-not $Force))

        {

            $hash = $devDetail.DeviceHardwareData

        }
```

then the hash is sent in the body of a HTTP call along with some other info

Here's the relevant part of the C# function

```
 string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);

            string HI = data?.hardwareIdentifier;

           

            var NouvelEquipement = new ImportedWindowsAutopilotDeviceIdentity {

                    GroupTag = req.Query["GroupTag"],

                    HardwareIdentifier = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(HI),

                    SerialNumber = req.Query["SerialNumber"],

                    State = new ImportedWindowsAutopilotDeviceIdentityState {

                        DeviceImportStatus = ImportedWindowsAutopilotDeviceIdentityImportStatus.Pending,

                        DeviceErrorCode = 0,

                        }

            };

       

            var retour = await graphClient.DeviceManagement.ImportedWindowsAutopilotDeviceIdentities

            .Request()

            .AddAsync(NouvelEquipement);
```

I get the following error which isn't helpful.

2022-12-23T18:07:27.944 [Error] Executed 'AjoutEquipement' (Failed, Id=xxxxxxx, Duration=4062ms)Code: InternalErrorMessage: {"_version": 3,"Message": "An error has occurred - Operation ID (for customer support): 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 - Activity ID: xxxxxxxxxx - Url: [https://fef.msua04.manage.microsoft.com/DeviceEnrollmentFE_2212/StatelessDeviceEnrollmentFEService/deviceManagement/importedWindowsAutopilotDeviceIdentities/microsoft.management.services.api.import?api-version=2021-01-22","CustomApiErrorPhrase"](https://fef.msua04.manage.microsoft.com/DeviceEnrollmentFE_2212/StatelessDeviceEnrollmentFEService/deviceManagement/importedWindowsAutopilotDeviceIdentities/microsoft.management.services.api.import?api-version=2021-01-22%22,%22CustomApiErrorPhrase%22): "","RetryAfter": null,"ErrorSourceService": "","HttpHeaders": "{}"}Inner error:AdditionalData:date: 2022-12-23T18:07:27request-id: xxxxxxxclient-request-id: xxxxxxxxxxxClientRequestId: xxxxxxxxxxx

I tried to convert the hardware Identifier string in every conceivable way to a byte array to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is so obvious now that I solved it ...

The powershell line

```
$hash = $devDetail.DeviceHardwareData
```

already provide a base64 encoded string of the hardware signature. So the only changes needed in the C# function were

```
byte[] HI = data?.hardwareIdentifier; //instead of string HI = data?.hardwareIdentifier; json provides direct conversion of base64 to byte array

HardwareIdentifier = HI, // instead of System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(HI),
```